# How to deserialize a custom object that has a parameter string with escaped JSON and dynamic key into Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON as below

```
{
   "fixedKey1" : "value1",
   "fixedKey2" : "value2",
   "fixedKey3" : "{\"DYNAMICKEY\":{\"innerKey1\":\"innerVal1\",\"innerKey2\":\"innerVal1\"}}"
}
```

I'm interested to extract only the inner JSON key and values in the fixedKey3.

Notice that fixedKey3 is a complex string that has a dynamic key that I cannot control. It is different in each response so that can never be a fixed key parameter.

So far I've written the below code, doing trial and error with no success

Below is the outer class of the entire JSON

```
class Outer {
  String fixedKey1;

  String fixedKey2;

  @JsonProperty("fixedKey3")
  public void setFixedKey3(String input) {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      //NEED help here
      mapper.readValue(input, InnerData.class);
  }
}
```

Below is the inner class which is supposed to contain inner values data.

```
class InnerData {
   String innerKey1;

   String innerKey2;
}
```

I'll be very grateful if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, there is a missing `}` at the end of `fixedkey3` value ?

Comment: fixed it @dariosicily. thank you for pointing out. it was a typo. The actual json has the closing } accurately.

Comment: @HelpMatters Does the value of "fixedKey3" always appear in this structure?

Comment: @BuildSlayer fixedKey3 is an optional field. If it has value at the source, it'll appear in the json, if it has no value at the source, then the field will be skipped in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem about your scenario is about the `"fixedKey3" : "{\"DYNAMICKEY\":{\"innerKey1\":\"innerVal1\",\"innerKey2\":\"innerVal1\"}}"` containing escaped double quotes : a first step to solve your question is using the [`readTree`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)) method and read the `JsonNode` obtained with [`asText`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText()) to get rid of the escaped double quotes like below:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
//s will contains {"DYNAMICKEY":{"innerKey1":"innerVal1","innerKey2":"innerVal1"}}
String s = root.get("fixedKey3").asText();
```

To obtain the  `"DYNAMICKEY"` dynamic key you can use the [`fieldNames`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fieldNames()) method and with the [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class)) method mapping the obtained `JsonNode` to one `InnerData` object as you expect:

```
JsonNode dinamycKeyNode = mapper.readTree(s);
String dynamicKey = dinamycKeyNode.fieldNames().next(); //<-- it will contains your dynamic key
//mapping the {"innerKey1":"innerVal1","innerKey2":"innerVal1"} to InnerData
InnerData innerData = mapper.treeToValue(dinamycKeyNode.get(dynamicKey), InnerData.class);
```

Note: for semplicity in the `InnerData` class the fields `innerKey1` and `innerKey2` are public.